# Expected result: Is alert required when changing settings?

Tags: mobile

Currently I am testing a Windows Phone application. It is a calendar application.
It has a settings page using where we can switch between two types of calendar.

[image]

After I change the option, is it wrong to display an alert to user that "Your default calendar is changed"?

My developer argues that it is against standard used in Windows Phone applications.

Comment: only two calendars available?

Comment: yes only two is available.My question is it wrong to display an alert on switching between calendar in windows phone

Comment: I agree that it's probably more suited to the UX stackexchange, but it has already received useful answers here, so I don't think it's worth migrating. @PramodKumarG - if you want it moved to UX though, flag it to mods and we'll migrate it. (Don't just raise the same question over there, better to migrate and avoid cross-site duplicates).

Comment: I've asked the UX mods in teacher's lounge if they want it, waiting to hear a response.

Comment: Either you can use a Save button or a tick on the right side. Developer is right, No need no show a popup as it may irritate user.

Answer (score 4):

If the user initiates the action, then no alert or message is required.

For example, when I change the Regional format settings which affect all applications on the phone that use date, time, etc. national convention formats no notification is displayed.

In situations like this you should compare similar applications or functionality, or review the associated guidelines such as  [User Experience Design Guidelines for Windows Phone](http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/8/6/D869941E-455D-4882-A6B8-0DBCAA6AF2D4/UI%20Design%20and%20Interaction%20Guide%20for%20Windows%20Phone%207%20Series.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

The default calendar notification can be shown under these criteria :

- if the calendar mode change replicates all over the application
- if the particular calendar mode can be used only for specific changes (for e.g certain functionality of the application will work only if the particular mode of calendar is selected)
- In General alert message should be shown if the **particular alert alters the entire functionality of the application**